# How to avoid "Maximum serialisation depth exceeded" when using insertmany in Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure

Saving Disk information from Azure:

```cs
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal("myclientId", "mytenant", "mysecretId", AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azure = Azure.Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription("mySubscription");
var groupName = "myResourceGroup";
var vmName = "myVM";
var location = Region.USWest;
var vm = azure.Disks.List();

Console.WriteLine("Getting information about the virtual machine...");

MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mylocalhost");
IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("VM");
var collection = database.GetCollection<IDisk>("Disk ");
collection.InsertManyAsync(vm);
```

When I save them to Mongodb, I get an error:

> maximum serialization depth exceeded (does the object being serialized have a circular reference?).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you probably have, as the error message suggests, a circular reference; perhaps the `IDisk` => `Manager` => (etc)? But the fix IMO: never serialize *implementations* - just serialize the *data* - so: instead of serializing the `IDisk`, create your own simple POCO type that just has the things that you want to serialize - name, size, whatever - and serialize *that*

Comment: I don't understand what you say. Can you give me a example? Thanks. This error I just meet with insertone and insertmany. In visual 15 I use insert and it work. But  in visual 19, they delete insert querry. So I use insertone and meet that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the `IDisk` that you're getting back from that API is resolving to a circular graph that the Mongodb isn't very happy with. The most simple fix, then, is : *don't serialize the `IFile`* - after all, it isn't your type, and you can't control it. Instead, create some type of your own that has *exactly what you want on it*, and serialize *that*. For example:

```cs
sealed class MyDisk // TODO: rename me
{
    public string Key {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string RegionName {get;set;}
    public int SizeGB {get;set;}
    // etc, but *only* the information you actually want, and *only* using
    // primitive types or types you control
}

...

var disks = (from disk in azure.Disks.List();
             select new MyDisk {
                 Key = disk.Key,
                 Name= disk.Name,
                 RegionName = disk.RegionName,
                 SizeGB  = disk.SizeInGB,
                 // etc
             }).ToList();
```

And store `disks`, which we *know* doesn't have a circular reference, because *we control it*.